# what is wrong with the following recursive directory search and file open?

Tags: c++, c, fwrite, fread, dirent.h

I am trying to access all files in a directory and do some thing on the files under this and the subsequent directories. For this operation I used dirent.h with windows and it manages to get all the files and open and close these files. My problem is, when i try to read some something from them and write to another, as shown below, i get the error shown at the end.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
FILE *test_file;
char buffer[51];
void listdir(const char *path) 
{
  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dp;

  //std::cout << "Dir: " << path << "\n";

  if(dp = opendir(path))
  {
    struct stat buf ;
    FILE *input_file;

    while((entry = readdir(dp)))
    {
        std::string p(path);
        p += "\\";
        p += entry->d_name;
        char fpath[250];
        //strcpy(fpath,path);
        if(!stat(p.c_str(), &buf))
        {
            if(S_ISREG(buf.st_mode))
            {
                std::cout << "    File: " << entry->d_name << "\n";
                sprintf(fpath,"%s\\%s",path,entry->d_name);
                input_file=fopen(fpath,"r+b");
                test_file=fopen("test_test.txt","a+b");
                if(input_file==NULL)
                {
                std::cout<<"\n Could not open\n"<<entry->d_name<<std::endl;
                continue;
                }
                if(test_file==NULL)
                    goto z;
                else 
                {
                    std::cout<<"\n Successfully Opened\n"<<fpath;
                    fread(buffer,50,1,input_file);
                    fprintf(test_file,"\n\n%s\n\n",fpath);
                    fwrite(buffer,50,1,test_file);

                    fclose(input_file);
                     fclose(test_file);
                    // free(buffer);
                }
z:
                if(test_file=NULL)
                fclose(test_file);
            }
            if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) &&  
         // the following is to ensure we do not dive into directories "." and ".."
                      strcmp(entry->d_name, ".")  && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") )
            {
                listdir(p.c_str());
            }
        }
        else
            std::cout << "ERROR in stat\n";
    }
   // delete buf;
    closedir(dp);
  }
  else
    std::cout << "ERROR in opendir\n";
  fclose(test_file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  listdir(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

It manages to open and read the first file but after the first file it will show the following error and open **dbgheap.c**

> HEAP[direntdir.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap(
>   002C0000, 002C5718 ) Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   direntdir.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   direntdir.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while direntdir.exe has
>   focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

EDIT:
corrected the errors with the **buf** variables.

Now i get

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> ... Expression:(buffer!=NULL) ...

Comment: You're both freeing and deleting `buf` (which in itself is highly suspicious) and AFAICT, never allocating storage for it anywhere (not even initializing it). (The mix of C-style code and C++ is quite confusing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables named `buf`:

```
char* buf;
...
struct stat *buf = new struct stat;
```

The latter hides the first and latter is `free()`d, even though it was created using `new`, and then reused without being reallocated.
The latter is also used as an argument to `fread()`. Rename `char* buf` and possibly make it local to the function and just use a stack allocated buffer:

```
char fread_buffer[51];
```

EDIT:

`char* buffer` never has memory allocated for it before it used in `fread()` so the call to `fread()` could be writing anywhere in memory. Change to:

```
char buffer[50]; /* as only 50 bytes are read from the file */
```

and don't call `free()` on `buffer` if it is declared this way.

Also, to simplify things just declare `buf` as:

```
struct stat buf;
```

and call `stat()`:

```
if(!stat(p.c_str(), &buf))
```

Making these two changes will remove all dynamic memory management from the code.

EDIT 2:

This `if` is an assignment, not an inequality check:

```
if(test_file=NULL)
    fclose(test_file);
```

should be:

```
if(NULL != test_file)
    fclose(test_file);
```

Comment: Did you change declaration of `buffer`?

Comment: i corrected my code according to your suggestions. But now i get **Debug Assertion Faild. .... Expression(stream==NULL)**

Comment: i corrected my code according to your suggestions. But now after reading all the files in a directory it gets the run time error **Debug Assertion Faild. .... Expression(stream==NULL)**

Comment: Including the `if (NULL != test_file)` ?

Comment: No problem: remove the `free(buffer);` as `buffer` is no longer dynamically allocated.